# Why is everything in my scene black in rendered mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I made my first model in Blender recently and worked on it for a while, when suddenly after entering rendered mode everything turned black, both meshes and lightning, but when I go into camera mode, its all there with normal lightning and materials, also render works fine. Im going crazy, because I cant find any fix and I dont know if this is something Ive done by accident or a bug, please help :(

https://we.tl/t-l2mSIMyHyH here's the link to the file, hope it works

https://we.tl/t-870SqILLua here are the screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You've enabled *Render Region* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> while in camera view. It allows you to only render the region you'll frame with your cursor. You can disable it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> or in the *N panel > View > View > Render Region*:

[image]

Comment: my lord and saviour, thank you so much <3